# C# Winforms App - Large Objects stuck in gen 2 - Memory Issues

Tags: c#, winforms, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have started memory profiling our app because we have recently received several reports about performance and out of memory exceptions. The app is developed in C# .Net Winforms **(.Net Framework 2.0)**

When the application started, the ANT profiler shows 17.7 MB objects live in Gen 2.

When the app starts, it reads the 77000+ zipcodes from a xml serialized file on the disk and saves in a Hashtable. Please see the sample code below

```
public Class ZipCodeItem
{
    private string zipCode;
    private string city;
    private string state;
    private string county;
    private int tdhCode;
    private string fipsCounty;
    private string fipsCity;

    Public ZipCodeItem()
    {
         // Constructor.. nothing interesting here
    }

    // Bunch of public getter/setter properties
}
```

Here is the static class that reads the serialized zip data from a file on disk and loads the zipcodes.

```
internal sealed class ZipTypes
{
    private static readonly Hashtable zipCodes = new Hashtable();

    public static ArrayList LookupZipCodes(string zipCode)
    {
        if (zipCodes.Count == 0)
            LoadZipCodes();

        ArrayList arZips = new ArrayList();

        // Search for given zip code and return the matched ZipCodeitem collection
        if (zipCodes.ContainsKey(zipCode))
        {
             // Populate the array with the matched items
        }

        // Omitted the details to keep it simple

        return arZips;
    }

    private static bool LoadZipCodes()
    {
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            // unzip it.. Omitted the details to keep it simple
            // Read the zipcodes from the flat xml file on disk and load the local zipCodes HashTable
        }
    }
}
```

This Class and the corr. ZipCodes are accessed all over the app.

About 14 meg out of 17.7 meg of Gen 2 objects are either zipCodeItems or Its child String classes.

I would like to change my code to some how NOT to keep these 77000+ zipcode item objects in memory (in a hashTable), but give the mapped zipCode items when the app needs it.

Any suggestions How to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: And you think that 14MB of RAM is causing an OOM exception?  It's not.  What's the alternative?  Read from disk every time a ZIP code is needed?  No, there's nothing wrong with storing that in memory from what I can see.

Comment: And on a side note, why are you using `ArrayList` and `Hashtable`?  Those classes are essentially deprecated. Prefer the collection classes found in the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace, i.e., `List<T>` and `Dictionary<K,V>`.

Comment: Erm, another improvement you could make is using `TryGetValue` instead of `Contains` and then performing another lookup.  You're doing twice the amount of work that you need to.

Comment: @Ed S - Thanks for your comments. This is legacy code that was written back in 2005. I can definetely improve this by using generic List/Dictionary classes.

Comment: when do the errors occur? On startup or after hours of working?

Comment: @Ed S - No, 14 MB wouldn't cause the OOM exceptions.. but having 10+ MB in gen 2, GC performs more gen2 sweeps which causes performance issues (from what I've heard), so trying to dispose these, but at the same time allow the app to lookup zipcode items., Not sure whether its possible or not., that's why I am here for suggestions..

Comment: Yeah, that happens, fair enough.  However, that 14MB hash is definitely *not* causing an OOM exception.  You need to look elsewhere in your code/profiling results.  Based on what you have told us I can assure you that you are heading down the wrong path,.

Comment: @ Henk Holterman - after hrs of working on the app., After 3 hrs of working on the app, the gen2 was up from 17.7 to 22.2 meg., so there could be other classes adding up in gen2

Comment: Thanks @Ed S. I will look for other culprits..

Comment: 14MB is in the noise for a modern app.  Really, I can say with 99% certainty that is not your problem, and you are talking about an OOM exception, which seems far more important.  Have you proven that you have a performance problem caused by the GC?

Comment: @Bradman: do take a look at the LOH, those zipcodes really didn't do it. I'm not familiar with ANT but there has to be a wider view. Also, report/log `GC.GetTotalMemory` and `Environment.WorkingSet`, just as rough check.

Comment: I give +1 to each single comment of Ed S.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to avoid answering the question directly in hopes of providing a more useful answer because I don't believe that the ~14MB associated with that hash is actually causing a problem.

You say that you are using the ANTS memory profiler.  That's a great tool and I have used it before, so perhaps I can help you track down the real problem here.

We can safely assume that your hash is not causing the `OutOfMemoryException` as it is nowhere near big enough to do so.  Keep it as it is now, except for two small changes:

1. Use a strongly typed `Dictionary<K,V>` instead of `Hashtable`.  `Hashtable` was essentially deprecated once .NET 2.0 introduce generics.  You can also go ahead and replace that `ArrayList` with a `List<T>`.
2. Instead of performing a `Contains` and then looking up the value in the hash, use `TryGetValue` instead.  This cuts the number of hash table lookups in half.  Now that may not be a performance bottleneck in your app, but I don't think it amounts to premature optimization either.

Now, onto the crux of the issue...

You have your profiler results.  Go back and look at where your memory is being allocated.  In order, check these things:

1. Is .NET holding most of the memory or is it native code (possibly creating a lot of objects that implement `IDisposable` and not calling `Dispose()` on them in a timely manner.)  If it's the latter you probably know where to look.
2. How does the Large Object Heap (LOH) look?  Is most of the memory allocated there?  Many large allocations can fragment the LOH and it may not be compacted for quite some time.  ANTS will tell you this at the top right of the results overview page.
3. Event Handlers.  When an object subscribes to an event a reference to the subscriber (method) is stored by the subscribee (by the MultiCastDelegate, i.e., the event object).  This may cause object lifetimes to never end and, over some amount of time, this may be adding up memory wise.  You need to make sure that, if there are objects being created and then going out of scope, it also unsubscribes from any events it had previously subscribed to.  Static events can be a killer here.
4. Use ANTS to track object lifetimes.  Similar to the above, make sure that there are no objects being kept alive inadvertently due to stale references.  This can occur more easily than you may think.  Again, look in areas where a relatively large number of objects are created and go out of scope, but also instances where other objects maintain references to them.  ANTS can show you this in the object graph.

That should at least give you a good picture of what memory is being allocated where.  You will likely need to run your program for some time under the profiler and simply watch memory usage.  If it steadily goes up then you can perform the steps I listed above in an attempt to isolate which objects are piling up.

Comment: Just a note, the items in 3, Event handlers, should show up as regular objects in a mem profiler. Solving them is a little special, diagnosing is not.

Comment: Yes, they won't show up as anything special, but the lifetime graph (object tracker?  I forget the name...) in ANTS will show the event name, so it makes things a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need some sort of storage along with an easy access mechanism.

I would suggest using some form of SQL based database.

We've had good success using SQL Compact Edition as it can be deployed without pre-requisites (aka a "private deployment"). Subsequently the integration story for querying is really tight - for example, using Linq to SQL is dead easy.

You could also look at SQL Lite or other providers. I would steer you away from a SQL Express dependency though just because it will be too heavy for these needs.

Also, seeing as though you would now be caching the zip codes in a database, you might also consider looking at some sort of "sync process" (say daily) for downloading and parsing your input XML file that you mentioned above (assuming the XML file is retrieved from some web service) or else you could just deploy the database already populated with the data.

Comment: I realize I'm trolling this thread a bit now, but this seems like an insane amount of overkill to replace a 14MB hash table that is definitely not causing the OOM exception.  There is no need to use a DB, I think the OP has missed the actual problem here.

Comment: Well, why not get rid of the whole 14MB of static memory use anyways? They did ask how to not store in memory at all. Plus, think of the potential increase in capabilities to the application by storing in a richer storage and query engine - e.g. zip code validation or auto-fill based on the other address components.

Comment: @Reddog: There's a performance and memory footprint price to be paid for SQL.  I would not add it without the requirements clearly dictating it's the best solution.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't recommend adding a database layer simply because the OP *might* need it someday.  That adds considerable complexity to an application that doesn't need it.

Answer (score 0):

> *When the application started, the ANT profiler shows 17.7 MB objects
>   live in Gen 2*

We had a similar issue and we find it is ok to keep these details in memoray **rather than loading it several times**. BUT it should not load in the start up. **Change the logic to load that at the first usage on demand.** Because there can be use cases where it is not using at all. No point of keeping that chunk in Gen2 for such cases.

> I am sure there may be sever memory leak issues than this one if you
>   have got memory issues in your application. ANT profiler is a good for
>   such cases :-)

Answer (score 0):

If your users are complaining about out of memory exceptions and you're addressing something that's taking 15MB of memory, you're looking in the wrong place.

The rest of my answer assumes that the 15MB really does matter.

Having said that, I would like to offer an alternative to the SQL solutions already proposed (which are good solutions, depending on your situation, if you determine that you really don't want to load the 15MB into memory).

We load 3GB of IP data into the process space of our web servers.  However, most of the IP addresses are not accessed most of the time (especially since we have a strong geographic bias in the user base, but still need to have the data available for visitors from less frequently seen parts of the world).

To keep the memory footprint small and the access very fast, we made use of memory mapped files.  While there's [support for them built-in to .NET 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx), you can still use them via interop calls in any previous .NET version.

Memory mapped files allow you to very rapidly map data from a file into memory in your process space.  SQL adds overhead for things you probably don't need in this situation (transactional support, key constraints, table relationships, etc... all great features in general but unnecessary to solve this problem, and cost something in terms of performance and memory footprint).

Comment: "The rest of my answer assumes that the 15MB really does matter" - but it doesn't. And MM files aren't going to help here.